# Pseudo after element not showing

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to add ::before and ::after pseudo-element for checkbox, but psudo after element not showing when we check the checkbox item

following css and html i have used

```css
.multiselect-container li input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative !important;
  left: -4px;
  top: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.multiselect-container li {
  position: relative;
}
.multiselect-container li label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 40px !important;
}
.multiselect-container li span::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 12px;
  top: 5px;
}
.multiselect-container li span::after {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #093c73 url(../images/tick.png) no-repeat 2px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 13px;
  top: 6px;
  display: none;
}
.multiselect-container li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .multiselect-container li span::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="multiselect-container">
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option1">Option1</label>
    <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your last selector is wrong. You are trying to select an element matching the selector `.multiselect-container li span` that the following sibling of the checked input field - but of course there is no such element.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the selector in the CSS vs the structure of the HTML.
You cannot do the selector as you had typed it in your CSS.

The span needs to come directly after the input:checkbox, not after the label.

```css
.multiselect-container li input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative !important;
  left: -4px;
  top: 2px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.multiselect-container li {
  position: relative;
}

.multiselect-container li label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 40px !important;
}

.multiselect-container li span::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 12px;
  top: 5px;
}

.multiselect-container li span::after {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #093c73 url(../images/tick.png) no-repeat 2px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 13px;
  top: 6px;
  display: none;
}

.multiselect-container li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="multiselect-container">
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option1">Option1
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```